# (13)Permission denied: access to /cgi-bin/test.cgi denied

Tags: linux, apache

I am trying out CGI-scripts for the first time but without success. I have read many tutorials and followed may threads in different forums but I can not make it work.
I am using a appache web server on a Fedora 10 machine.
I always have problem with

```
[Wed Oct 21 20:47:36 2009] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Wed Oct 21 20:47:36 2009] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Oct 21 20:47:36 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Oct 21 20:47:36 2009] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Oct 21 20:47:36 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.2.9 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I need help.
This is what my environment looks like.

```
uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.27.5-117.fc10.i686 #1 SMP Tue Nov 18 12:19:59 EST 2008 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

ls -l /var/www/cgi-bin/
total 36
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   106 2009-10-21 18:29 index.html
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11089 2009-02-24 20:11 squidGuard.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5720 2009-02-24 20:11 squidGuard-simple.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5945 2009-02-24 20:11 squidGuard-simple-de.cgi
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   110 2009-10-21 17:38 test.cgi

apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.11 (Unix)
Server built:   Mar  6 2009 09:12:25

perl -version
This is perl, v5.10.0 built for i386-linux-thread-multi
Copyright 1987-2007, Larry Wall
```

My script

```
cat test.cgi
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
print "Hello, world!\n";
```

The error message I gen when I try to access the web page server "http://192.168.50.29/cgi-bin/test.cgi" looks like this:

```
[Wed Oct 21 21:00:27 2009] [error] [client 192.168.50.69] (13)Permission denied: access to /cgi-bin/test.cgi denied
```

I have added the line:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
```

to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

I just can not make it work.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: The error message I gen when I try to access the web page server "http://192.168.50.29/test.cgi" looks like this:

     [Wed Oct 21 22:31:32 2009] [error] [client 192.168.50.69] (13)Permission denied: exec of '/var/www/html/test.cgi' failed
     [Wed Oct 21 22:31:32 2009] [error] [client 192.168.50.69] Premature end of script headers: test.cgi

Comment: Why, oh why, oh why does root own those files?

Comment: Find out which user / group owns the apache server process and make sure it owns your cgi scripts and has exec permission.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Check your os permissions for test.cgi and be sure the user or group you are using to run your apache it has read access.*

EDIT - The problem is with permissions, but not with read permissions, as you are using SELinux, you need to worry about your file context. Check this [thread](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-41377.html) at fedora forums, it explains quite a few options to solve your problem.

Comment: According to the question test.cgi has 777 permissions - i.e. read, write, execute for user, group, and other - so all users can do anything.

Comment: True, I missed that bit in my first read with unformatted code.

Comment: That fedora forums thread says to set the context of the CGI file like so: `chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t file.cgi`. Maybe this used to be right but now the correct label is `httpd_sys_script_exec_t`. Setting this with `chcon` works, but you can also reset the SELinux labels recursively on the whole cgi-bin directory using `restorecon -R /var/www/cgi-bin/`. Then `ls -lZ file.cgi` shows the permissions as: `-rwxr-x---. 1 root apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_exec_t:s0`. Once this works, add a reminder comment to your httpd.conf file because "documentation is automation".

Answer (score 6):

**1**.**FIRST CHECK THE HTTPD.CONF** FILE.Set the script directory as follows in the httpd.conf.
Here you'd need to make sure you find the right httpd.conf file.For example, in my Debian, the default httpd.conf is /etc/apache2/sites-avaialbe/default.

```
<Directory "dir_name">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
<Directory>
```

**OR** you could just use the default /cgi-bin folder.

**2**.Set the **execute permission** for the test script.

```
chmod +x script_name
```

Answer (score 3):

check your fstab if the mounted filesystem have permission to execute

```
UUID=xxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xx     /mnt/mountpoint     ext4     rw,user,exec      0      0
```

the **exec** part is important

Answer (score 3):

SELinux prevented Apache from accessing the cgi script in my case.
A quick-n-dirty fix that worked for me was turning off SELinux:

```
vim /etc/sysconfig/selinux
set "SELINUX=disabled"
reboot
```

Comment: Well, now you have the problem that you aren't running with SELinux ;) I believe in your case you have created a cgi-bin directory in an other location which means that you have to add a new file context to the policy list by using the command  ' semange fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t "/path/to/directory(/.*)?" ' and then ' restorecon -Rv /path/to/directory ' to apply the new file context to the files. Check out man semanage-fcontext and go to EXAMPLE section, there is a great example of this process there.