# Python CGI scripts using GET values

Tags: python, cgi

I have a CGI script in python. I want to know how to run the CGI script itself alongside a normal python script (in this case a file writing device) using the variables received through the GET method. Here is the code:

```
window.location.href = "http://[URL]/python_scripts/get.py?first_name=mlb&last_name=406"
```

This is in the main script, the get.py file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import modules for CGI handling 
import cgi, cgitb 

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name')

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (first_name, last_name)
print "</body>"
print "</html>"

f = open("/var/www/data.txt", w)
f.write("Hello from %s %s") % (first_name, last_name)
f.close()
```

in the error.log file it says:

```
[Tue Jun 23 19:07:07 2015] [error] (13)Permission denied: exec of '/var/www/python_scripts/get.py' failed
[Tue Jun 23 19:07:07 2015] [error] [client [IP]] Premature end of script headers: get.py, referer: http://[URL]/python_scripts/testScript.py
```

**EDIT**
The script runs fine without the f=open etc part, making me suspect a permission error

**EDIT**
Now solved. I needed to apply "chmod 777" permissions to the function file, the file performing the operation, and the text file itself. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Have you configured your web-server to treat py-files as CGI in the /var/www/python_scripts ? Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599728/13permission-denied-access-to-cgi-bin-test-cgi-denied

Comment: Yep, the directory /var/www/python_scripts/ has been enabled if you will, testScript.py is innthere

Comment: Then maybe permissions are not right as suggested in the accepted answer in the linked question. And as hinted there may be those extended permissions.

Comment: I did sudo chmod +x get.py, still doesn't work, but it runs fine when I take out the file writing part

Comment: I don't see a "cgi-bin" part in the URL. Usually scripts outside cgi-bin are denied.

Comment: Alex - cgi-bin is not in the URL, I have other scripts that work fine outside of there, but would you recommend I move my scripts there?

Comment: Can you update your question with information, that cgi script runs fine (as cgi script), when "f = open..." part is removed. Also, if it is the case, then check if http server user has write permission in the directory the script tries to write.